# Xquery delete type query using lookup list

Tags: xquery, xquery-update

Need help constructing xquery to delete data from XML File that contains data for Google Products data feed.

I have a long list of ID numbers in a spreadsheet column that need to be removed - these are numeric.

Below is the xml schema.  I need to select all the records where `<g:id>` = "my string of numbers" , then delete them from the file.

Thanks for the help!

```
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
 <channel>
   <title></title>
   <link></link>
   <description></description>
  <item> 
    <title></title>
    <link></link>
    <description></description>
    <g:id></g:id>
    <g:condition></g:condition>
    <g:price></g:price>
    <g:availability></g:availability>
    <g:image_link></g:image_link>
    <g:brand></g:brand>
    <g:mpn></g:mpn>
    <g:product_type></g:product_type>
  </item>
 </channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This XQuery**:

```
declare namespace g = "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0";

<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <channel>
  {
    let $vIds := (1,3)
     return
       /*/*/*[not(g:id = $vIds)]
   }
  </channel>
</rss>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
  <rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
  <channel>
    <title></title>
    <link></link>
    <description></description>
    <item> 
      <title>Item 1</title>
      <link></link>
      <description></description>
      <g:id>1</g:id>
      <g:condition></g:condition>
      <g:price></g:price>
      <g:availability></g:availability>
      <g:image_link></g:image_link>
      <g:brand></g:brand>
      <g:mpn></g:mpn>
      <g:product_type></g:product_type>
    </item>
    <item> 
      <title>Item 2</title>
      <link></link>
      <description></description>
      <g:id>2</g:id>
      <g:condition></g:condition>
      <g:price></g:price>
      <g:availability></g:availability>
      <g:image_link></g:image_link>
      <g:brand></g:brand>
      <g:mpn></g:mpn>
      <g:product_type></g:product_type>
    </item>
    <item> 
      <title>Item 3</title>
      <link></link>
      <description></description>
      <g:id>3</g:id>
      <g:condition></g:condition>
      <g:price></g:price>
      <g:availability></g:availability>
      <g:image_link></g:image_link>
      <g:brand></g:brand>
      <g:mpn></g:mpn>
      <g:product_type></g:product_type>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
   <channel>
      <title/>
      <link/>
      <description/>
      <item> 
         <title>Item 2</title>
         <link/>
         <description/>
         <g:id>2</g:id>
         <g:condition/>
         <g:price/>
         <g:availability/>
         <g:image_link/>
         <g:brand/>
         <g:mpn/>
         <g:product_type/>
      </item>
   </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitre! this worked great for me. I'm sure the other reply would too but I'm not sure what to do with that variable.  Newbie at BaseX.

Comment: @DanM: I am glad my answer was useful. If so, could you, please, as per SO's established way of expressing gratitude, accept the answer? This is done by clicking on the check-mark next to the answer.

Comment: @DanM: I have updated my answer with an iven simpler solution.

Comment: Thanks i checked the answer I'm new to SO so did not know this yet.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the [XQuery-Update `delete`-function](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Updates#delete)

```
delete node doc("mydata.xml")//item[g:id = (1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 12)]
```

If you don't want to touch your original data, use [`modify`](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Updates#Non-Updating_Expressions).

```
copy $c := doc("mydata.xml")/
modify delete node $c//item[g:id = (1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 12)]
return $c
```

`=` compares with some set-semantics, it returns true if of of the items on left side equal one on the right.

Comment: Thanks, i discovered xbase too with your link.  I installed it, learning it now. so i added my xml doc to a new db, opened it up, then i paste the query in editor, i get undefined variable $x.  What do i define this as?

Comment: Oh sorry, `$x` just contained my XML snippet for testing. Just remove it if you opened the database. For other systems, you may need to add doc("whatever") instead.